# UINavigationController centered button using obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

I'm trying to add a centered button in my navbar header, confused as to how I can do it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UIImage *meImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/me.png", kSelfBundlePath]];
UIBarButtonItem *meButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:meImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(twitterButton)];


[self.titleView //i read this can be used to like set it but i havent been able to figure it out
```

help would be appreciated, pretty new

Comment: you want to add button in center?

Comment: yep pretty much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this code

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [buttonContainer addSubview:button0];

    //add your spacer images and button1 and button2...

    self.navigationItem.titleView = container;
```

Comment: yep I did thank you for providing it, looks exactly what I was trying to get working & has some extra stuff I appreciate, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this way

```
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"Title here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button sizeToFit];

[topView addSubview:button];

[topView sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = topView;

-(void)buttonAction:(Id) sender {

NSLog(@"button clicked");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its pretty straight, you can use titleView property of UINavigationItem :

```
    -(void)addCenterButton {
    UIImage *meImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/me.png", kSelfBundlePath]];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame::CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
    [button setImage:meImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(twitterButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
    }
```

Comment: yep got this to work, thank you for your help & others who provided similar answers